# On-click drop-down nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a column list with some drop-down menus and I needed the Jquery for the drop-down to make it work.

I have found some Jquery for this but the problem is when you have two menus with ul and li, like this.
HTML:

```
<ul class="list-menu">
<li class="sort-menu">4</li>
    <div class="sort-list-dropdown">
         <ul class="sort-list">
             <li>4</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

When you duplicate this two times and then when you click the 4 on the class that says `sort-menu`, it will put up two menus containers and that class is `sort-list-dropdown` I have been playing with JS I got from somewhere and I'm getting confused about this issue.

JavaScript:

```
    $("ul.list-menu > li").click(function () {
    var X = $(this).attr('id');
    if (X == 1) {
        $("ul.sort-list > li").hide();
        $(this).attr('id', '0');
    } else {
        $("ul.sort-list > li").show();
        $(this).attr('id', '1');
    }
});

//Mouse click on sub menu
$("ul.sort-list > li").mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});

//Mouse click on my account link
$("ul.list-menu > li").mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});


//Document Click
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    $("ul.sort-list > li").hide();
    $("ul.list-menu > li").attr('id', '');
});
```

I get some of the variables but I do not think it's the code. I think I need to input a new variable but I do not know what does it need for it.

If anybody knows how to accomplish this, then please reply back to me.

Comment: So, the only problem is that both of your menus are opening and closing in unison?

Comment: You're targeting the same class. So if you are creating two elements with the same class name, you're jQuery is going to see them both. You need to target $(this).parent('ul');

Comment: I see in JS you're looking for attribute "id" - but in your html none of the elements have any ids... If the problem is as Nick above me describes - I'd suggest looking at jQuery closest and children methods - http://api.jquery.com/closest/ and http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: He's using the ID as a form of a *toggle*. Notice his if/else statement.

Comment: You can only have `li` tags inside a `ul` tag. Having the `.sort-list-dropdown` div is invalid HTML

Comment: @NicholasHazel, Where do I put '$(this).parent('ul');' at?

Comment: With your markup? Nowhere. It isn't going to work with the current structure you have laid out.

Comment: @NicholasHazel, Okay is there a way to clean it up and use it so, it could work?

Comment: Sure, kind of. Mind if I fiddle something up without your HTML?

Comment: @NicholasHazel, Yea, sure.

Comment: Answered sir. Let me know if that will fit your bill.

Answer (score 1):

I have one answer for this problem. Please try this code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.sort-list-dropdown').hide();
     $('ul.list-menu li').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.sort-list-dropdown').toggle();
     });
});
```

In code '**click**', you can change it to '**hover**'.

Comment: Good call. I was waiting for the callout to avoid using a `var` boolean for his toggle :-P.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try something like this:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/bmwBr/5/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>

    <li class="sec">Heading One</li>
    <li><ul>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>

        <li class="sec">Heading Two</li>
        <li><ul>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Third</li>
            <li>Third</li>
        </ul></li>

    </ul></li>

    <li class="sec">Heading One</li>
    <li><ul>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
    </ul></li>

</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('li.sec').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('li').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
.sec {
    background:#efefef;
    padding:25px;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

#### Try something like this:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/bmwBr/5/

Comment: Always try to keep your JS minimalized. With this code, you just put a `sec` li class on any title you want, and an expanded li structure below

Comment: I like it but I need a on-click so, when you click the 4, it will bring up the things to sort.

Comment: I'm sure you do, but that wasn't the question asked. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved the question asked, so future coders are able to reference it for a specific problem. If you want further clarification, please copy the code to a new question.

Comment: Other than ID names, I don't see any reference to you needing to sort data, so we need further clarification. Hence the request to post a new question :-) I juggle questions all day, and somebody may very well have a better answer than me for a different question.

Comment: I don't want a actual sort data. I just want two menus and next to it, it will be a 4 representing the sort you are on. Then when you click it, it pop-ups with a div container with the extra links.

Comment: k....? [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/bmwBr/7/) Keep in mind you'll have to modify it slightly to get it to start out collapsed. I still don't know what you mean by `sort`... I really think this deserves another gander, as this post is likely dead at this point. The question has been answered.