# On-click drop-down nav menu (part 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have made a topic about this in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248633/on-click-drop-down-nav-menu).

I have explain everything in that topic.

I have look around at stackoverflow, trying to find ideas of this and I kinda did.

I have played around with some code and JavaScript I found.

HTML:

```
<div class="sort-list-menu-dropdown">
<span class="list-sort-title">Columns:</span>
<ul class="list-menu">
    <li class="default-sort-menu">
        4
        <ul class="sort-list">
            <li>4</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.sort-list { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
$("ul.list-menu > li.sort-menu").click(function () {
   $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

The JavaScript does work but when you duplicate them with the same id called `sort-list-menu-dropdown` and when you click the first text called "4", it will bring up the menu called `sort-list` But this is where it messes up. When you dubplicate this, then when you click the first menu text called "4", it will bring it up but when you click the second menu, the first menu don't hide.

If anybody knows how to achieve this, it will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$("ul.sort-list").hide();` This will hide all the elements matching ul.sort-list, but your next line will toggle the one that was clicked on and show it.

```
$("ul.list-menu > li.sort-menu").click(function () {
   $("ul.sort-list").hide();
   $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

Comment: this work but when you click out of the menu and click the page, it will hide it when you click away.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to change `.sort-menu` to `.default-sort-menu` since it's the correct class name.

Secondly, when click on a list item to show the submenu belongs to that `ul.sort-list`, you can just hide other submenu from other `ul.sort-list`

```
$("ul.list-menu > li.default-sort-menu").click(function () {
    $("ul.sort-list").hide();
   $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrq69/)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the byproduct of copying/pasting code but make sure you are closing your div. But you probably don't actually need that div.

As Felix pointed out, you need **default-sort-menu** as opposed to **.sort-menu**

And finally, toggling the class should work just fine for what you want to do.

See http://jsfiddle.net/thechrisjordan/sx73T/1/

```
$('ul.list-menu > li.default-sort-menu').click(function () {
   $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('sort-list');
});
```